# How to prevent Vector3.SignedAngle from constantly checking angle?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a raycast that shoots down, and then a Vector3.SignedAngle to check for angles, and if there is an angle, do something.

But this should only be activated/checking for angles while I am standing on a non-flat surface. But it's constantly checking so even if I am on flat ground, it will make some of my other movement mechanics very wonky and not work due to the constant angle check which will make my player do something. So it will essentially constantly overlap with any other of my other non-related code.

I have tried (if angle < 1f && > 0.1f) so that it will not check until I am on an angle, but I know a condition like that does not work, and also wrapping the entire raycast in an angle check does not work either (no errors).

```
void FixedUpdate()
    {
        RaycastHit hit;

        if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, out hit, 2f))
        {
            float angle = Vector3.SignedAngle(hit.normal, Vector3.up, transform.right);
            if (angle < 0.1f)
            {
                // Do something
            }
            else if (angle > 0.1f)
            {
                // Do something
            }
        }   
    }
```